# jquery dom traversal via parent/child

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have several instances of

```
(".wrappingdivclass > .hovercontents > .hovercontent2")
```

on a page.. all need to behave independently but call the same jquery. As you can see its two blocks of identical HTML...

how would I go up/down the dom tree to keep the hover/showhide on ONLY the stuff within the wrappingclass div, and not affect everything the next wrappingclass div also.

```
<div class="wrappingclass" id="notthesecondone">
 <div class="hoverheaders">
     <p class="hoverheading">on hover display stuff</p>
     <p class="hoverheading1">on hover display stuff1</p>
     <!-- iterate, as needed !-->
    </div>
     <div class="hovercontents">
      <p class="hovercontent">stuff</p>
      <p class="hovercontent1">stuff1</p>
              <!-- iterate, as needed !-->
  </div>
    <div class="wrappingclass" id="notthefirstone">
 <div class="hoverheaders">
     <p class="hoverheading">on hover display stuff/hide stuff1</p>
     <p class="hoverheading1">on hover display stuff1/hidestuff</p>
     <!-- iterate, as needed !-->
    </div>
     <div class="hovercontents">
      <p class="hovercontent">stuff</p>
      <p class="hovercontent1">stuff1</p>
              <!-- iterate, as needed !-->
  </div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
//does not work
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hovercontent").show();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".hoverheading").hover(function()
  {
     jQuery(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").show()
    jQuery(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
jQuery(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").show()
jQuery(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").siblings().hide();
```

with

```
jQuery('.hovercontent').hide();
jQuery(this).closest('.hovercontent').show
```

#### Edit

Replace `hover` with `mouseover`

#### Final Edit,

Its acutally like this.. (inside DOM ready)

```
$("p[class^=hovercontent]").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
$("p[class^=hoverheading]").mouseover(function() {
    $("p[class^=hovercontent]").hide();
    $(this).closest('.hoverheaders').next().find('p').eq($(this).index()).show();
});​
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/68UVj/

Comment: Also, you should name space the $ variable into jQuery on document-ready if you're concerned about issues with conflict. `jQuery(function($){ //code });`

Comment: tried

        jQuery(this).next('.hovercontent1')

and

        jQuery(this).closest('.hovercontent1')

neither seems to work :-/

Comment: how would that help? @Ohgodwhy

Comment: replace `hover` with `mouseover`

Comment: toggle on hover, need to avoid toggle off on mouseout.

Comment: then remove `$("p[class^=hovercontent]").hide();` from `mouseover`

Comment: I'll give it a shot today. Rephrasing the "p[class^hovercontent]" to "p.hovercontent" since its jquery. (? or does jQuery take that syntatx and I don't know?) 

 Will post results.

Comment: jquery does supports that syntax, it means all classes starting with hovercontent. `^` is similar to `^` we use in regex